# RewriteRule htaccess and hidden php file for all

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem in RewriteRule htaccess:
example:
my php file is main.php
we need to when user trying to **www.mysite.com/hello** , then show **www.mysite.com/main.php**
for this expamle we have below code in .htacces:

```
# BEGIN Htaccess
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^hello/*$ main.php
```

but in this code if user can open **www.mysite.com/hello** and **www.mysite.com/main.php**

I need if user trying **www.mysite.com/main.php** then show error *404* but if trying for **www.mysite.com/hello** view content of **main.php**

thank you;)

Comment: Try this : RedirectMatch 404 "/main*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to match against the actual request here:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /main\.php
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]
```

You can add that just under `RewriteEngine On` if you want. The other way of dealing with this is to maybe check for `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in your **main.php** script and if it's `/main.php`, instead of serving content, return a 404 response.

Comment: Does not work to me. Are there something wrong in your accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can't 404 main.php neither can you 301 it to /hello as it'll go into infinite loop. 
You'll have to check the url in main.php and if it is different than hello, redirect it to /hello